# InterruptedException occurred when using Vertx's executeBlocking with JDK ExecutorCompletionService starting from Vertx v4.3.0

Tags: java, vert.x, interrupted-exception, vertx4

While upgrading vertx version from 4.2.7 to 4.3.0, we are seeing InterruptedException is being thrown wherever we have used Vertx executeBlocking with JDK ExecutorCompletionService. This issue is observed from Vert.x version 4.3.0 onwards. Is there any changes to executeBlocking in 4.3.0 ?

We are calling  method B from method A, where method B has code to create different threads using JDK ExecutorCompletionService and method A has Vertx execute blocking code from where method B is being called.

Below are the stack trace for reference

2024-03-06 15:25:08,942 [DS_ASSET_DISCOVERY_HANDLER-0] ERROR PortScanWrapper:144 - Exception occured in PortScanWrapper java.lang.InterruptedException: null
at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$Sync.lockInterruptibly(ReentrantLock.java:159) ~[?:?] at java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock.lockInterruptibly(ReentrantLock.java:372) ~[?:?] at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:432) ~[?:?] at java.util.concurrent.ExecutorCompletionService.take(ExecutorCompletionService.java:200) ~[?:?] at com.sup.deviceidentification.PortScanWrapper.startScan(PortScanWrapper.java:134) ~[identification-5.0.23-SNAPSHOT.jar:?] at com.sup.core.handlers.DeviceIdentificationHandlerImpl.portScan(DeviceIdentificationHandlerImpl.java:221) ~[core-5.0.23-SNAPSHOT.jar:?] at com.sup.core.handlers.DeviceIdentificationHandlerImpl.identify(DeviceIdentificationHandlerImpl.java:415) ~[core-5.0.23-SNAPSHOT.jar:?] at com.sae.commons.utility.VertxTest.identifyDevice(VertxTest.java:125) ~[main/:?] at com.sae.commons.utility.VertxTest.callCollector(VertxTest.java:67) ~[main/:?] at com.sae.commons.utility.VertxTest.lambda$0(VertxTest.java:39) ~[main/:?] at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$null$0(ContextImpl.java:159) ~[vertx-core-4.3.0.jar:4.3.0] at io.vertx.core.impl.AbstractContext.dispatch(AbstractContext.java:100) ~[vertx-core-4.3.0.jar:4.3.0] at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.lambda$executeBlocking$1(ContextImpl.java:157) ~[vertx-core-4.3.0.jar:4.3.0] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136) [?:?] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635) [?:?] at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) [netty-common-4.1.106.Final.jar:4.1.106.Final] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840) [?:?]

This issue is observed with vertx v4.3.0 onwards.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/51560/paulo-lopes can you help here.